# How to update already registered service Castle Windsor

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, castle

I'm a beginner to the DI containers.

I'm using third party framework and it has a class like below

```cs
public class PurchaseOrderAppService : IPurchaseOrderAppService, IAutoRegister
    {
        private readonly IEmail _email;

        public PurchaseOrderAppService(IEmail email)
        {
            _email = email;
        }
    }
```

All classes that inherits IAutoRegister interface are automatically registered by the third party framework. 
Email class is like below

```cs
public class Email : IEmail, IAutoRegister
{
    public Send(string message)
    {
        //Send a message
    }
}
```

What I want is that I want PurchaseOrderAppService class to use another class called MyEmail instead of Email.

```cs
public class MyEmail : IEmail
{
    public Send(string message)
    {
        //Send a message another way
    }
}
```

How can I update already registered service by framework?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the name of the third part framework? How does it work?

Comment: @YacoubMassad, The name of the third party is not important here, What I want to know is how I can update the service already registered in DI container.

Comment: Do you have access to the container? Can you show the existing registrations?

Comment: I can access the container, but I can't see the registration code. it must be something like this 
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IAutoRegister>().WithServiceSelf());

Comment: Try this `container.Register(Component.For<IEmail>().ImplementedBy<MyEmail>().IsDefault());` it should override the registration for `IEmail`.

Comment: Oh,, I forgot to mention that in some other classes, Email class are used, So I can not change the default registration. I only need to use MyEmail for PurchaseOrderAppService class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating registered service is not a right way to do with IoC container and is not something you need. I would suggest you have a look at https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/inline-dependencies.md and https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-one-by-one.md#supplying-the-component-for-a-dependency-to-use-service-override

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Thuan,

In the second link, there is method named ServiceOverrides which is obsoleted, and I could use **DependsOn** instead,

```cs
IocContainer.Register(
    Component.For<IEmail>()
    .ImplementedBy<MyEmail>()
    .Named("Email.MyEmail"),
    Component.For<IPurchaseOrderAppService>()
    .ImplementedBy<PurchaseOrderAppService>()
    .Named("PurchaseOrderAppServiceWithMyEmail").IsDefault()
    .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(typeof(IEmail), "Email.MyEmail")));
```